# Mongo aggregate group by pair

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation

I have collection like this

| User | Receiver | IsRead |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | false |
| B | A | false |
| A | B | false |
| A | C | false |
| C | A | false |

How can I group it by both User and Receiver to get result like this

| Combined Field | Messages |
| --- | --- |
| AB OR BA | 3 |
| AC OR CA | 2 |

tried this

```
$group: {
    _id: {$or: [{userId: "$recipientId", recipientId: "$userId"}, {userId: "$userId", recipientId: "$recipientId"}]},
    messages: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$isRead', false]}, 1, 0]}} // count
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `$group` key to be `$setUnion` of the `User` and `Receiver` field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "$setUnion": [
          [
            "$User"
          ],
          [
            "$Receiver"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "Messages": {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              $not: "$IsRead"
            },
            "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uLCExBgl51T) for your reference.